# Wifi USB adapter/receiver available

Tags: drivers, wireless

Ive been using Ubuntu for a while now,recently my cousin accidentally hit my laptop and ever since then, my wifi card has been damaged
I searched about this online and got to know that USB adapters are a great solve, the only problem is not many of them are available for linux and when they are, theyre for ethical hacking on Kali Linux, i just need a simple solve for my problem...
a good wifi adapter that has linux drivers and supports dual band, Im just a student and not into the hacking stuff.
any help would be reallly really appreciated
thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a hardware recommendation request.

Comment: Please check here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397914

Answer (score 1):

- Older dongles have a higher likelihood of working out-of-the-box. 802.11n, for example, isn't the newest, but it's still very fast.
- Check for verified/tested compatibility with https://ubuntu.com/certified
- Purchase from vendors that have a generous return policy.